# Meaning of nomic relation

Tags: terminology

I came across the concept of "nomic relation". I can't decipher what this term means. I can't find a meaningful definition in the sources either. So could any of you explain to me what does it mean?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Nomic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomic) : From Ancient Greek *nomikós*, “relating to laws”, from *nómos*, “law, custom”. Thus "relating to a law".

Comment: More details about the context may help...